# Price and text shopping card overlap in RWD theme

Tags: rwd-theme

When I go to a category products are display but the product price and the text for adding the product to the shopping card overlap. This happens in every browser and also on mobile devices.

See picture.

I noticed this happens when the description for the product contains more words.

Can somebody please help me how to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the JS in the "Product Listing - Align action buttons/links" section of the `skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js` file was not optimized to work with non-English translations. The current JS assumes that the height of the .actions is a constant. I've updated this code to allow for the .actions content to be any height.

In order to fix the problem, replace the contents of the alignProductGridActions function with this:

```
var alignProductGridActions = function () {
    var gridRows = []; // This will store an array per row
    var tempRow = [];
    productGridElements = $j('.products-grid > li');
    productGridElements.each(function (index) {
        // The JS ought to be agnostic of the specific CSS breakpoints, so we are dynamically checking to find
        // each row by grouping all cells (eg, li elements) up until we find an element that is cleared.
        // We are ignoring the first cell since it will always be cleared.
        if ($j(this).css('clear') != 'none' && index != 0) {
            gridRows.push(tempRow); // Add the previous set of rows to the main array
            tempRow = []; // Reset the array since we're on a new row
        }
        tempRow.push(this);

        // The last row will not contain any cells that clear that row, so we check to see if this is the last cell
        // in the grid, and if so, we add its row to the array
        if (productGridElements.length == index + 1) {
            gridRows.push(tempRow);
        }
    });

    $j.each(gridRows, function () {
        var tallestProductInfo = 0;
        $j.each(this, function () {
            // Since this function is called every time the page is resized, we need to remove the min-height
            // and bottom-padding so each cell can return to its natural size before being measured.
            $j(this).find('.product-info').css({
                'min-height': '',
                'padding-bottom': ''
            });

            // We are checking the height of .product-info (rather than the entire li), because the images
            // will not be loaded when this JS is run.
            var productInfoHeight = $j(this).find('.product-info').height();
            // Space above .actions element
            var actionSpacing = 10;
            // The height of the absolutely positioned .actions element
            var actionHeight = $j(this).find('.product-info .actions').height();

            // Add height of two elements. This is necessary since .actions is absolutely positioned and won't
            // be included in the height of .product-info
            var totalHeight = productInfoHeight + actionSpacing + actionHeight;
            if (totalHeight > tallestProductInfo) {
                tallestProductInfo = totalHeight;
            }

            // Set the bottom-padding to accommodate the height of the .actions element. Note: if .actions
            // elements are of varying heights, they will not be aligned.
            $j(this).find('.product-info').css('padding-bottom', actionHeight + 'px');
        });
        // Set the height of all .product-info elements in a row to the tallest height
        $j.each(this, function () {
            $j(this).find('.product-info').css('min-height', tallestProductInfo);
        });
    });
}
```