# Why is the theme of Magento 1.9.0 so broken?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd, rwd-theme, bug

we have a really weird problem with magento frontend. It looks really broken. Some buttons are over other button - like the 2 links at the right top on the main page or that the "to cart"-button is floating over the price...
also another thing: after a reinstallation of magento the description disappiered and we don't know how to bring it back.. (look screenshot)

we didn't change anything on the theme or design, it is like that right after the installation. Is it usually that broken or do we have to care about some special setting befor/while/after the installation??

hope for help!
[image]

Comment: Without any more information on what you did or what exactly had changed between when it worked and currently it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: it doesn't work befor. we installed it for the first time and it's buggy from the beginning. we tried to install it many times but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: So this is the default rwd theme? Sounds like you are missing some files or some of them are corrupt. I would suggest doing another clean install just to be sure

Comment: we did it like 10 times, even on different servers (also on local) and it still looks like this

Comment: Sorry, without further information I don't think anyway will be able to help you

Comment: could it be, that the theme is not optimized for other languages ? becouse our magento shop is in german

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the RWD theme is not optimized for non-US languages. So you will need to make some small CSS adjustments to make things like the top links work properly.

The issue with the buttons overlapping the name/price on category pages can be fixed using the code I shared here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/38272/2142

Comment: thanks for the answer. that just explain the visual bugs. i used your shared code and it works fine - thx!